# On set of permutations in which any two permutations differ by $1$ at some index

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, permutations

Let $S$ be a susbet of $S_n$ such that for every $\pi , \tau \in S_n , \exists i\in \{1,...,n\}$ such that $|\pi(i)-\tau(i)|=1$ ; then is it true that $|S| \le {n \choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $\pi \in S$, write down the binary string of length $n$ which has a $0$ in the $i^{\text{th}}$ position if $\pi(i)$ is even and a $1$ in the $i^{\text{th}}$ position if $\pi(i)$ is odd.

This string must contain $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ $0$'s and $\lceil n/2\rceil$ $1$'s, so there are exactly $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ choices for what this string might be. And given $\pi, \tau$ in $S$ such that $|\pi(i) - \tau(i)| = 1$, the strings corresponding to $\pi$ and $\tau$ differ in the $i^{\text{th}}$ position.

So w never write down the same string twice, which means there are at most $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ permutations in $S$.